# Freeze a TensorFlow Estimator's graph (to be converted to Core ML)

Tags: tensorflow, coreml, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to convert the [Iris estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/premade_estimators) example to use with iOS/CoreML, but haven't been able to figure out how to export a frozen graph.

Following the guides [Programmer](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/) and [Mobile](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models) guides I get an error when trying to convert a trained (Estimator) graph.pbtxt (and model.ckpt):

```
freeze_graph --input_graph=graph.pbtxt --input_binary=false --input_checkpoint=model.ckpt-1000 --output_graph=frozen_graph.pb
```

gives the following error:

```
[...]freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 683, in _ValidateAndSliceInputs
variable) TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("dnn/hiddenlayer_0/bias:0", shape=(100,), dtype=float32)
```